# jq find keys whose value is an array containing a specific element

Tags: arrays, json, key, jq

the file is

```
{
    "ContentKey--4-0-47--Vovb1BQ": ["infra", "qa", "qa-ContentKey-4-0-47-Vovb1BQ", "internal-qa-Conten-WebServi-19E4PUWHRGD44-460820639.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com", "plan--default"],
    "ContentKey--4-0-47--zjOkiQ": ["svc", "dev", "dev-ContentKey-4-0-47-zjOkiQ", "dev-Conte-WebServi-KXJXZBDY113W-2116785917.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com", "plan--default"],
    "IdGenService--2001-4-22--CJUFaMQ": ["svc", "dev", "dev-IdGenService-2001-4-22-CJUFaMQ", "dev-IdGen-WebServi-R7RVXSYAV92W-304073075.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"],
    "IdGenService--2001-4-22--Uhf9CTQ": ["svc", "qa", "qa-IdGenService-2001-4-22-Uhf9CTQ", "internal-qa-IdGenS-WebServi-RT5BI5EEVZP3-665537643.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"]
}
```

I want to find the list of keys whose array value have the entry `svc`

i could get the following to work

```
cat list.json | jq '. | map(select (. | contains(["svc"])))'
```

But the output is the value array and not the key itself

```
[
  [
    "svc",
    "dev",
    "dev-ContentKey-4-0-47-zjOkiQ",
    "dev-Conte-WebServi-KXJXZBDY113W-2116785917.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com",
    "plan--default"
  ],
  [
    "svc",
    "dev",
    "dev-IdGenService-2001-4-22-CJUFaMQ",
    "dev-IdGen-WebServi-R7RVXSYAV92W-304073075.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
  ],
  [
    "svc",
    "qa",
    "qa-IdGenService-2001-4-22-Uhf9CTQ",
    "internal-qa-IdGenS-WebServi-RT5BI5EEVZP3-665537643.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The top-level object in your json is an object, not an array.  So `.[]` would only yield its values and discard the keys. Use [`with_entries/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) to filter that object.  This converts an object to an array of key/value pairs and back with which you can apply filters to.

```
$ jq --arg key 'svc' 'with_entries(select(any(.value[]; . == $key)))' list.json
```

Also, you should avoid using `contains/1` here.  It's applied recursively so it will also match strings that contain the substring `svc`.  i.e., `"Foosvcbar"` will be matched.

Comment: Your answer works for me. I tried upvoting but dont have enough reputation points.

Comment: You might not be able to upvote yet but it is your question and you can accept the answer if your question is sufficiently answered. Consider accepting for this (and for your other questions) if this works for you.

Answer (score 10):

With your input, the following filter yields the output as shown:

```
to_entries[] | select( .value | index("svc") ) | .key
```

Output:

```
"ContentKey--4-0-47--zjOkiQ"
"IdGenService--2001-4-22--CJUFaMQ"
"IdGenService--2001-4-22--Uhf9CTQ"
```

In cases like this, using `index/1` is both simpler and (potentially much) faster than using `any/2`.